# Integer translations of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions can never be complete in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, wavelets

This is Exercise 10.18 in A Basis Theory Primer, Christopher Heil. I am just reading this book and not a homework.

> Given an arbitrary $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, let $T(g):=\{g(x-k)\}_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$. Then, show that $\overline{\mathrm{span}\{g(x-k)\}_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}}\not= L^2(\mathbb{R})$, that is, the set of all finite linear combinations of elements of $T(g)$ is not dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I tried playing around with the ideas in the book, e.g., suppose that $T(g)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then, since the Fourier transform is unitary from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to itself, in particular, continuous, the sequence of their Fourier transform 
$M(\hat{g}):=\{\mathrm{e}^{-2\pi\mathrm{i}k\xi}\, \hat{g}(\xi)\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$
is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and tried to derive a contradiction but didn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the Fourier transform, the problem reduces to show that, for any function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the set of products $pf$, where $p$ is a trigonometric polynomial $p(t)=\sum c_k \exp(2\pi i k t)$, is not dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. The key point here is that $p$ is $1$-periodic.

If $f=0$, the conclusion is obvious, so exclude this case. Then, for a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, there exists a set $A$ of positive measure, with $\operatorname{diam} A<1$, and such that  $|f|>\epsilon$ on $A$.

Since $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{A+n}|f|^2 <\infty$, it follows that there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $|f|<\epsilon/2$ on most of the set $A+n$ (that is, on a subset that comprises, say, $99\%$ of the measure of $A+n$).

It's impossible to approximate the function $\phi = \chi_A + \chi_{A+n}$ by any function of the form $pf$. Indeed, to have small integral $\int_A |pf-1|^2$ we must have $pf$ close to $1$ on most of the set $A$. But then $|pf|$ is less than $2/3$ on most of the set $A+n$, so $\int_{A+n} |pf-1|^2$ cannot be small.

Comment: I do not understand why $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{A+n}|f|^2 <\infty$ holds. If $f=\chi_A$, then
$\|f\|_{L^2}<1$ but don't we have $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{A+n}|f|^2 
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{diam}(A)^2
$?

Comment: The integral of $|f|^2$ over the real line is finite. So if you integrate over disjoint subsets of real line, and add these integrals, the sum is finite.

Comment: If they are disjoint, sure. But what I really did not understand was you meant $A+n$ by the translation, i.e., $A=[a_0,a_1]$ to $A+n=[a_0+n,a_0+1]$, which now I understood. (thus for the same reason we do not have $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{A+n}|f|^2 
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{diam}(A)^2$.)

Comment: First, $A$ need not be an interval. It's a measurable set. Having diameter less than $1$ ensures that it is disjoint from any of its integer translates. The sum with diam that you wrote is meaningless.

Comment: Ah. I see.>Not necessarily an interval. Huh, thanks.>Diam less than 1 is for disjoint translation. Could you elaborate? I think it is meaningful allowing it to be divergent, it's just the equality does not hold.>The sum with diam that you wrote is meaningless.